# How to sort a DateTime-column in DataView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataview

I have a gridview with some columns and I need to sort the gridview by a date-column. But I fail in sorting it correctly. This is the code that I use:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Meldingsdatum asc";
gvOutlookMeldingen.DataSource = dt;
gvOutlookMeldingen.DataBind();
```

Can someone help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/p/1267353/2393006.aspx

Comment: not really an answer but a link to it. post an answer so I can accept it

Comment: The answer there, as openshac has suggested as well, is: "Check the DataType property of the DataColumn and make sure it's set to DateTime."

Answer (score 2):

DataView stores date or anything as string type. Thus when you sort it sort by string. To sort it as DateTime , you need to convert it to DateTime before adding any data as follows,

*dt.Columns["Date"].DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");*

Answer (score 2):

My code snippet hopefully shows the need to set the column as typeof(DateTime) before you can sort it properly

```
        EntityCollection result = serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(querybyattribute);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("Created On", typeof(DateTime));

        foreach (Entity entity in result.Entities)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["Title"] = entity.Attributes["title"].ToString();
            dr["Created On"] = entity.Attributes["createdon"];

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Created On desc";
        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = sortedDT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you column of type DateTime, if not then it probably needs to be.  Do this right at the start before you populate the table.  Alternatively you could create a second column of type DateTime and use that but it's a little messy :-)

Comment: I have to set the datatype of that column to DateTime initially. Then I can sort it